# How to uncheck checkbox when clicking on row in jqgrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Is there a way to get the behavior with checkboxes similar to this one with radio buttons http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWidthRadioButton2.htm
with included checkbox for selecting/deselecting all.
Row selection and checkbox on that row may not be linked, just like in the example with radio buttons.

**UPDATE:**

Here is my snippet:

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
            datatype: "local",
            data: mydata,
            colNames: ["Client", "Date", "Amount", "Tax", "Total", "Shipped via", "Notes"],
            colModel: [
                {name: "name", width: 70, frozen: true},
                {name: "invdate", width: 80, align: "center", sorttype: "date",
                    formatter: "date", formatoptions: {newformat: "d-M-Y"}, datefmt: "d-M-Y"},
                {name: "amount", width: 75, formatter: "number", sorttype: "number", align: "right"},
                {name: "tax", width: 55, formatter: "number", sorttype: "number", align: "right"},
                {name: "total", width: 65, formatter: "number", sorttype: "number", align: "right"},                    
                {name: "ship_via", width: 100, align: "center", formatter: "select",
                    edittype: "select", editoptions: {value: "FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;IN:Intim", defaultValue: "IN"}},
                {name: "note", width: 70, sortable: false}
            ],
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [5, 10, 20],
            pager: "#pager",
            gridview: true,
            rownumbers: true,
            sortname: "invdate",
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: "desc",
            caption: "Handling of changing of chechboxes in the grid",
            height: "auto",
            multiselect: true,
                multiboxonly: true,
            beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
              var $target = $(e.target), $td = $target.closest("td"),
                  iCol = $.jgrid.getCellIndex($td[0]),
                  colModel = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel");
              if (iCol >= 0 && $target.is(":checkbox")) {
                  return false;
              }

              return true;

            },
            onSelectRow: function (rowid, isSelected, event) {

                var rowData = $("#list").jqGrid("getRowData", rowid);

                var checkbox = jQuery(this).find('#' + rowid + ' input#jqg_list_'+rowid+'[type=checkbox]');

                if ($(checkbox).is(':checked')) {
                    $(checkbox).attr('checked', false);
                }
            },
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yNw3C/12696/

As you can see, the problem is when I click on the row that was previously checked, it will uncheck the checkbox.

Comment: Not real clear on exactly what you're looking for.  Can you post a JsFiddle with what you have so far and a description of how it's not correct?

Comment: I'm trying to get the behavior where row selection will not check checkbox on that row, and where checking checkbox will not select that row. 
I hope I was clear.

Answer (score 0):

Clicking on the row will not check your checkbox unless there is code in place to explicitly make this happen.  So I'm going to guess that what your're having trouble with is your row's onclick handler being called when you click on a checkbox.  to prevent this, add stopPropegation():

```
$('table checkbox').click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

There is also stopImmediateProgagation(), but stopPropagation() should be enough for your situation.

If this does not correct the problem, please post a JsFiddle or provide a live link so that it will be easier to see exactly what your code is doing.

UPDATE:
your onRowSelect handler (line 60) is targeting all checkboxes in the row, it will work like you expect if you update line 64 to target the specific checkbox you are interested in:

```
var checkbox = jQuery(this).find('#' + rowid + ' input#jqg_list_'+rowid+'[type=checkbox]');
```

instead of

```
var checkbox = jQuery(this).find('#' + rowid + ' input[type=checkbox]');
```

UPDATE2:

Yes, this doesn't completely solve your problem.  I've attempted several methods on your fiddle and it seems like every reasonable method of trying to deal with this just ends up fighting the plugin too much.  According to the docs, the 'multiselect: true' and 'multiboxonly: true' options should be enough.  I would file a bug report with the plugin maintainer.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but it doesn't solve my problem.
I updated question with snippet and link on jsfiddle.

Comment: I updated my answer above, it makes minimal modification to you original code to achieve the desired behavior.

Comment: Maybe it was confusing with all those columns with checkboxes. I simplified grid and updated in my question your proposal so you can see that it is still not working as it is supposed to be. Take a look please.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(function () {
    $('#toggleAll').click(function (event) {
                var checked = event.target.checked;
                $("input[name='checkIds']").each(function (e) {
                    this.checked = checked;
                })
                event.stopPropagation();
     });
   }

  var chkBoxs = "<input type='checkbox' id='toggleAll' />";
  var colNames = [chkBoxs];
```

I have the same trouble with you when I use the checkbox component in jqGrid. Above snippe code is the valid method to solve problem.
In real, the event mechanism of js lead to the trouble.

Comment: @EJoshuaS This is an answer. You just have to read the complete text.